# Как сделать двухслойный background-image?

Tags: css

[image: Мне нужен вот такой фон]

[image: Но скопировав из авокода слой, получается такое]

Что делать? Как добавить цвет снизу?

Comment: используйте opacity: 0.5;

Comment: так не получается(

Comment: @Ingrid Я так понимаю, вам надо чтобы цвет фона смешивался с картинкой, верно?

Comment: @Ingrid Вам подошёл мой ответ? Если да, то отметьте его как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа). Если нет — то оставьте комментарий, в чём именно.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы цвет фона смешивался с картинкой, используйте CSS-свойство `background-blend-mode`.

Допустим есть картинка

[image: Кот]

Применяем `background-blend-mode: multiply;`:

```css
.cat {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkAMf.jpg");
  background-color: pink;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat">
</div>
```

Подробней можете почитать [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-blend-mode/).

Единственное но: данное решение не поддерживается IE.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, картинка прозрачная.

Значит, единственное что нужно сделать — указать цвет в свойстве `background` одновременно с ссылкой на картинку:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb3KZ.png') no-repeat #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло такое: `z-index: 100;` `color: #000;`.

Comment: А можете выложить исполняемый пример, хочу наглядней увидеть ваш способ?